# Is there any way to get reversed nested serializers in django rest framework?

Tags: json, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

Suppose i have two models:

```
class Region(models.Model):
    region_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True, verbose_name="Region Name"
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.region_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Regions"

class Country(models.Model):
    region_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Region,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name="Region id",
    )
    country_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, unique=True, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="Country Name"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Countries"
```

Now, when i access the country model through Djnago REST Framework, as /api/countries

I get `country_name` and `region_id` for example

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "country_name":"Taiwan",
    "region_id": 1
  },
  ...
  ...
]
```

Is there any way to get the result like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "country_name":"Taiwan",
    "region_id": {
        id: 1,
        region_name: "Asia",
      }
  },
    ...
    ...
]
```

I have tried nested serializer example as on the DRF website, but it returns a list of countries if we get the regions api.

like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "region_name":"Asia",
    "countries": 
      [
          "Taiwan",
          "Japan",
          "Vietnam",
          ...
      ]
  },
    ...
    ...
]
```

I need to know the region name of the country in one api get request. Right now i am using 2 requests. One to get country, and then get region name from region id.

This is my model and serializer if i use nested serializer.

```
class Region(models.Model):
    region_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True, verbose_name="Region Name"
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.region_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Regions"

class Country(models.Model):
    region_id = models.ForeignKey(
        related_name="countries"
        Region,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name="Region id",
    )
    country_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, unique=True, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="Country Name"
    )
```

```
class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = "__all__"

class RegionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     countries = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='country_name'
     )
    class Meta:
        model = Region
        fields = ["id", "region_name", "countries"]
```

Comment: Can you show your serializer (and nested one)?

Comment: Here you go, i have edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you only get the slugs of the related `Country`s is because you use the `SlugRelatedField`, that will thus list the slugs of the `Country`s.

The trick is to make extra serializers that will serializer the related object(s). For example:

```
class ShallowRegionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Region
        fields = '__all__'

class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    region_id = ShallowRegionSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = '__all__'

class CountryRegionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = '__all__'

class RegionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     countries = CountryRegionSerializer(
        many=True,
        read_only=True
     )
    class Meta:
        model = Region
        fields = ['id', 'region_name', 'countries']
```

Now you can make use of the `CountrySerializer` and the `RegionSerializer`. When serializing objects, it will use other serializers, like the `ShallowRegionSerializer` and `CountryRegionSerializer` to serialize related object(s).

Comment: Thanks Willem, you helped me a second time. The thing i needed was ShallowRegionSerializer.